# What does eclipse do at GWT Breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, gwt

In a big GWT web project, if suppose we place a breakpoing over a button click function, What action that it takes place in eclipse when the breakpoint is reached? Is that any timer JS is running till we continue to pass throught the break point? Just curious to know and am sorry if this sounds silly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In DevMode, your Java code runs in Java. The JSNI code is sent to the browser (through the DevMode plugin you installed there), and when it needs to call back to Java code (such as when handling events) it calls through the plugin, which doesn't yield to the browser until the code server (the DevMode Java app) responds.

So when you break in your Java code, the DevMode plugin in the browser is still waiting for the response, and the browser is blocked waiting for the plugin to return (in Chrome, it only blocks the current tab's content, because of the multi-process architecture, but in Firefox for instance, it blocks the entire browser, you cannot even switch to another tab or open a menu).